# How to deal with multi-index in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gvRa.png

which has three sub-levels of indices. The first one is a number of 4 digits, the second is a date, and the last one is an index from the original dataframe.

I want to rename each level by `['District_ID', 'Month']` and to drop the third level. I already tried to drop the last one, and I used:

```py
DF.index = DF.index.droplevel(2)
```

As a result, the third level is gone but the second one duplicates for all the rows. In addition I want to rename the column indices. How can I accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistaken impression of what is going on. Take this simple sample frame

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    (lev_0, lev_1, lev_2) for lev_0, lev_1 in zip("ab", "xy") for lev_2 in range(2)
)
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": range(4)}, index=midx)
```

```
       col
a x 0    0
    1    1
b y 0    2
    1    3
```

and look at the result of

```
print(df.index)
df = df.droplevel(2)
print(df.index)
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', 'x', 0),
            ('a', 'x', 1),
            ('b', 'y', 0),
            ('b', 'y', 1)],
           )

MultiIndex([('a', 'x'),
            ('a', 'x'),
            ('b', 'y'),
            ('b', 'y')],
           )
```

This should be exactly what you want? If you print the `df` after the `droplevel` it looks as if there's something strange happening with the first level, but this is only for making the print clearer.

As for the renaming:

```
df.index.names = ["lev_0", "lev_1"]
```

or

```
df.index.set_names(["lev_0", "lev_1"], inplace=True)
```

both lead to

```
             col
lev_0 lev_1     
a     x        0
      x        1
b     y        2
      y        3
```

Or if you want to rename the columns (not clear to me what you are looking for), then you could do

```
df.columns = ["new_col"]
```

or

```
df = df.rename(columns={"col": "new_col"})
```

```
     new_col
a x        0
  x        1
b y        2
  y        3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a clarification when I drop the 3rd level this is what I get:                                                       
                           col                                                                        ID   Month                                                                                    
a    2020-01-31    0                                                              
   **2020-01-31** 1

Comment: @Lambda Sorry, but I don't really understand? It would be best if you could provide a copy-&-pastable sample of your dataframe. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for inspiration. Otherwise communication is rather hard (posting images of data/code goes actually against the SO standards: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).